# AAC audio source with Cordova not playing properly.

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using PlayCordovaAudio() function to stream audio (Shoucast).

The MP3 audio source is playing well with this code:

playCordovaAudio('the.url:PORT/;stream.mp3');

But, when trying to play an AAC audio source, the audio starts and stops right away. Even when using the same function:

playCordovaAudio('the.url:PORT/;stream.aac');

Here is the app that I am developing. If you want, you can download it and test it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.es611radio.kreactivamente1610001
 (the first radio play is from the .mp3 audio source, the second one is an AAC audio source).

Any idea how could I fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like the source is shoutcast DNAS - is it DNAS version 1.9.x or version 2.x? - by the way, if it's the same url:PORT then you're trying to play  an MP3 stream and forcing AAC codec

Comment: They are different url:PORT. 
The MP3 source has the SHOUTcast Server v2.5.0.715.
And the AAC source has the SHOUTcast Server Version 1.9.8

Comment: @JaromandaX Any suggestion?

Comment: yes, use DNAS 2.5.0.715 for AAC as well ... 1.9.8 would stream to winamp, and a few other media players only ... give AAC the same love you give MP3